# Visability if statement: if css display is not none, do

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, visibility, display

I have this Javascript function and it does not work. Got no errors from brackets. I am aware, that this also can be done with visibility, but in my case this seems better and I want to stay with it if that is possible.

I have three buttons and by hovering each, the matching div will fadeIn (.one, .two, .three). That code (not shown here) already works great.

Now I want to show .hello, when all three divs are faded in (aka display is not 'none' anymore like I wrote in the CSS file, because Javascript changed that by fading them in, right?).

CSS:

```
.hello {
    display: none; }
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(function() {

    if (jQuery('.one').css('display') !== ('none') &&
        jQuery('.two').css('display') !== ('none') &&
        jQuery('.three').css('display') !== ('none')) {

            jQuery('.hello').fadeIn();
        }
});
```

Is something wrong with that?

Comment: Why do you put brackets around 'none'? Btw. when do you execute this code?

Comment: Try ```console.log($('.one').css('display'));``` to see what it's value is. Perhaps this will help you debug.

Comment: have you tried using `!jQuery(".one").is(":visible")`, that should also work for elements hidden with `display:none`

Comment: oh and do you actually check that each div is faded in after a single one is faded in? With your code, the check will be made when the page finished loading, and I doubt that at that time, the user managed to hover over all three divs

Comment: Thank you Thomas! I didn't realize the time of the checking was the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there is a better solution but it came to my mind at first. The function should be executed on change not once.

```js
//you did this part already.
$("#1st").hover(function(){
  $(".one").fadeIn();
});
$("#2nd").hover(function(){
  $(".two").fadeIn();
});
$("#3rd").hover(function(){
  $(".three").fadeIn();
});

//checks when hover
$("#1st,#2nd,#3rd").hover(function(){
    // same code 
    if (jQuery('.one').css('display') !== ('none') &&
        jQuery('.two').css('display') !== ('none') &&
        jQuery('.three').css('display') !== ('none')) {
            jQuery('.hello').fadeIn();
        }
})
```

```css
.one,.two,.three,.hello{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="1st" value="1">
<input type="button" id="2nd" value="2">
<input type="button" id="3rd" value="3">
<br><br>
<div class="one">1.content</div>
<div class="two">2.content</div>
<div class="three">3.content</div>
<br><br>
<div class="hello">Hello!</div>
```